# Logic and Set Theory Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

Demonstrate a logical system, and proposition set $S$, such that:

1. There exists a formula $\beta$ such that $S\nvdash \beta$
2. There exists a formula $\alpha$ such that $S \vdash \alpha \wedge S \vdash ¬(\alpha)$

---

Can someone please help me with that?

I do not understand what I should do here..

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What is your definition of "logical system"?

Comment: @EricWofsey Like HPC

Comment: That's an example, not a definition.

Comment: @EricWofsey I am sorry I don't know how to define it in English...

Comment: @EricWofsey Maybe Propositional Logic System Proof

Comment: You can give your definition in another language and let others translate it for you.

Comment: @EricWofsey Apparently, it is just called "Proof System", that built from Axioms and Inference Rules.

Comment: Does it need to have any inference rules? It will be easier to control deductions when you don't have any!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take one axiom: $\neg p$ (where $p$ is a propositional variable). Take one rule of inference: Substitution of arbitrary formulas for propositional variables.

In this proof system, you can prove exactly the formulas of the form $\neg\theta$. In particular, you cannot prove $p$, but you can prove both $\neg p$ and $\neg\neg p$.

Comment: Thank you very much! You chose the set $S=${$¬p$} ?

Comment: @CalculusLover In this case, S might as well be empty, as I've made $\neg p$ an axiom. Alternatively, you could take a system with no axioms (and only the substitution rule), and then S should be $\{\neg p\}$.